# How to get all the max lenght of each column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

is there a way to obtain the max length for each column in a dataframe?. I know how to do it one by one with object/numeric type, but the problem comes out when there is so much columns which i have to and also de type of each column (object/int/float/date).

Example:

```
     a   b    c 
  1 aad sdsd  ds
  2 sds  wewe 5
```

Max a= 3 ; b=4 ;c=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `apply` `str.len` per column and get the `max`:

```
df.astype(str).apply(lambda s: s.str.len()).max()
```

output:

```
a    3
b    4
c    4
dtype: int64
```

As dictionary:

```
d = df.astype(str).apply(lambda s: s.str.len()).max().to_dict()
```

output: `{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 4}`
Or using a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {k: df[k].str.len().max() for k in df}
```

Comment: Yes, but this solution only works when the data is object type :(.

Comment: @Juan this was the original requirement ;) What if the last cell was 5000 in your update?

Comment: Yes, was my bad no specify everything. If 5000 the max character should be 4

Comment: Then simply convert to string first: `df.astype(str).apply(lambda s: s.str.len()).max()`